# how switch between two voltages

Tags: power, power-electronics, low-power

I have a project and I need use ISP to send codes to ATMEGA328P, the problem is that my ISP programmer works with 5V and my system works with 3.3V. I know [ATMEGA328P supports 5V](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) but other components in my system (like a radio) not, and I like run it in 8MHz .

I used a LM1117-3.3 to reduce ISP 5V to 3.3V but I have a problem when power the system with external 3.3V, the regulator is in short because its VOUT is getting 3.3V. to solve it just put a diode as shown in the picture below, but the diode has a 0.7V voltage drop which forces my circuit to work with 2.6V, this is causing problems on my radio.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this? I did not want use more jumpers ....

[image: My circuit]

Comment: If you don't use +5V, why don't you simply disconnect that pin and power the system with 3.3V?

Comment: During the prototype stage I would like to feed the project by USB (ICSP) instead of batteries. But if anyone suggest something I will remove the 5V and use batteries even during upload

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev - his ISP(ICSP) uses 5V.

Comment: @Renato Tavares - can't you connect your ext 3.3V supply at the output of your LM1117 chip to bypass it?  You don't *have to* use a diode there, do you?

Comment: ultra low VF Schottky like PMEG1020EA ~ 150 mV voltage drop at 100 mA

Comment: wow, PMEG1020EA is very cool

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear to me why you can't just feed 3.3 volts into the point you indicate, so this is a long shot. The traditional way to prevent problems where the output of a regulator is higher than the input is to connect a diode like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flhk8g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Specifically a *schottky* diode so that its voltage drop is lower than that of the parasitic diode.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I didn't think they existed in CircuitLab, but I managed to figure out how to make one, thanks!